# Accessing/modifying the React server code

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How can I access/change the web server part of React?

When I run `react-scripts start` it automatically starts a web server for me. This web server is very useful because it listens for changes to my code and automatically updates my app as I make changes, making development very easy.

Now I want to inject a `<script>` tag into `public/index.html` on the server side. This is because the script URL is stored in a database (i.e. the `src` is dynamic for each user) and the script needs to be loaded synchronously (so this can't be controlled by React - e.g. by using React Helmet - because the script needs to run before React loads).

I can easily to do this by using Express to serve the file after React has been built, but by doing this I lose the development capabilities such as automatic updating as I dev the site.

So is there any way for me to access the web server part of my React project? Either directly, so I can just add some extra code that gets run on each request, or indirectly (by using some middleware or something)?

Many thanks!